# How to give another chance to input if conditions are not met

Tags: python, regex, string, input

I want to check if an user types an word only including strings.

So, if the user types a number (32) or a compound of number+string (Fight2win), I want to let the user to type once again before move on.

I have problems on giving another chance to input when the prior input contains a number. So, I was going to use the "While loop", but now I can't figure out how to break it after it finishes checking.

Also, I was trying to go every single alphabets and see if it can be converted into integer or not. I know there is other ways like isalpha, but still I need to know how I can give another chance to type and re-check the second input if it only contains string..

here is my original code.

```py
while True:
    x = input(f"Please type a word.").lower()

    for i in x:
        try:
            int(x)
            print("Type Error: Please insert alphabets only!!!")  
           
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You need to consider the following two situations (and hence two methods). The first method presents a rather universal/generic solution if you only want to drop inputs with digits (*note that we have alphabets, digits and special characters*).

Let us consider these inputs:

- `values = ["10", "me@home2", "me2@ho10me", "me@home", "myhome"]`
- **Method-1** will accept "me@home" and come out of the while loop
- **Method-2** will accept only "myhome" from the list of values above before coming out of the while loop.

You need to choose which method to use depending on your usecase.

### Method-1: Using `regex`

This will not allow inputs with

- digits alone
- alphanumeric data

But, this will allow special characters, if you need them.

```py
import re
result = ['0']
pat = re.compile('\d')
# Control printing of message if 
# invalid input is provided
verbose = 0 # set 1 for printing

while result:
    value = input("Enter alphabets only: ").lower()
    result = pat.findall(value)
    if result and verbose>0:
        print(f" >>> Invalid Input: {value} \n >>> Try again...")

## Output
# Enter alphabets only: 10
# Enter alphabets only: me@home2
# Enter alphabets only: me2@ho10me
# Enter alphabets only: me@home --> LOOP EXITED HERE
```

### Method-2: Using `str.isalpha()` or `str.isalnum()`

This will not allow inputs with special characters as well as digits.

```py
value = '0'
# Control printing of message if 
# invalid input is provided
verbose = 0 # set 1 for printing

# Method-2.A
while not value.isalpha():
    value = input("Enter alphabets only: ").lower()
    if not value.isalpha() and verbose>0:
        print(f" >>> Invalid Input: {value} \n >>> Try again...")

# Method-2.B
while value.isalnum():
    value = input("Enter alphabets only: ").lower()
    if value.isalnum() and verbose>0:
        print(f" >>> Invalid Input: {value} \n >>> Try again...")

## Output
# Enter alphabets only: 10
# Enter alphabets only: me@home2
# Enter alphabets only: me2@ho10me
# Enter alphabets only: me@home
# Enter alphabets only: myhome --> LOOP EXITED HERE
```

---

Use `str.isalpha()` to check if it is purely alphabet or not.

```py
values = ['abcd', '10', 'abc23knh']
[value.isalpha() for value in values]

## Output
# [True, False, False]
```

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Does this address your question? If it helped please consider **`voting-up`** and **`accepting`** (if applicable). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess it is working however im suffering to print error message only when the input is in wrong format

Comment: You can not print error message (treating it as error) while expecting the program to keep going on. If you only want to notify the user of "non-compliant input", just add a print statement in the loop  at the appropriate place.

Comment: I have updated the code for printing notifications when invalid input is provided

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me, now user can try as many times he want, and you can specify the breaks

```
start=[]
while True:
     start=list(input(f"Please type a word.").lower())
...
```

Rest your logic follows since you asked how to incorporate multiple tries for user.

Happy coding.